# Support different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, screen

I have been seeing, that to support different screen sizes, you have to use Constraint Layout. Is it possible to achieve this support on different screen sizes without using Constraint Layout? If so, is there a document or video where I can see how to do it?

Comment: @javdromero I meant not to use constraint layout...

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is another better way to do this. Anyway the constraint layout it's not that hard to find out if you really care about it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this but you can create a new resource directory from the res directory in android studio. There you can add your screen's height and width and create a new layout folder. Create a layout directory as per your need and create designs as per screen sizes.

If you do not want to use a constraint layout then I think you can apply it this way. I will suggest you that go for the smart way then this hard way.